# how to display an error from another controller (angular1.6)

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, controller, components, angular1.6

Here I have my `index` controller which is in the index component which includes several functions that I call later in another controller:

```
userParticipate() {
    this.ApiPartners.feliwayParticipate().then(res => {
      this.$state.go('feliwayMain.success')
    }).catch((err) => {
      this.errorMessage = err.data.error
      console.log('err', this.errorMessage)
    })  

    }
```

And now here is another controller that is in another component to which I pass the function (thanks to bindings):

```
validateChoosePet(optin, response) {
    if (this.selectedPet) {
      if (optin == true) {
        this.ParticipateOptin()
      } else {
        this.Participate()
        console.log('erruser', this.errorMessage)
      }
     }
    }
```

The function `ParticipateOptin()` is the same as `userParticipate()` it just allows users to have newsletter.

Everything works fine, but I would like to display errors that happen in `userParticpate()` at `validateChoosePet ()`. I'm getting errors in the `console.log` just impossible to display them

I hope I have succeeded in making myself understood, sorry for my English.

Comment: What do you mean by display? Do you already have the error in another controller and you just can't display it, or do need to share the error between controllers in the first place?

Comment: sorry, I did not express myself well. I want to display the error when I click on a button, when I click on the button the error appears in the console but not on the web page.Here is the template: 
 `<div class="feliway__form__btn">
    <button type="submit" 
class="feliway__btn" 
ng-disabled="formChoosePet.$invalid">valider ma participation</button>
      <p class="feliway__error" ng-if="$ctrl.errorMessage">
{{ ::$root.t.photoshoot.choose_pet_none }}</p>    
  </div>`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey and yes i need to share the error between controllers in the first place

Comment: Think of having global variable to share. One solution: have a parent controller which holds the variable that both child controllers can access. Second is to use `$rootScope`, a global scope. Since it's watched every time, filling it in with variables and making it heavy is a bad idea (makes your app slow). So instead you can use a service/factory that stores your variables and you can update/access them on some changes in any controller.

Comment: To check for changes you can use angularjs constants: `app.constant('YOUR_EVENTS', {somethingChanged: 'variable-SOMETHING-changed'})`. Then you can broadcast a change with `$rootScope.$broadcast(YOUR_EVENTS.somethingChanged)` and detect it somewhere else with `$rootScope.$on(YOUR_EVENTS.somethingChanged, youFunctionCallback)`. (Don't forget to inject YOUR_EVENTS constant in your controllers)

Comment: ok I understand, thank you very much I will test all that. I'll start by adding the variable in the service

Comment: More [related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers) for your tests

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Super thank you I look at it if it does not work. But I think you put me on the right path :) .